# scala type conversion to java generic class

Tags: java, scala

I want to convert this code from java to scala :

trait ThriftPailStructure[T <: Comparable] extends PailStructure[T] {

```
public T deserialize(byte[] record) {
 // A new data object is constructed prior to deserialization
 T ret = createThriftObject();
 try {
   getDeserializer().deserialize((TBase <?, ?>) ret, record);
 } catch (TException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
 return ret;
 }
 ...
 }
```

Where TBase is defined in java as :

```
public interface TBase <T extends org.apache.thrift.TBase<?,?>, 
F extends org.apache.thrift.TFieldIdEnum> extends java.lang.Comparable<T>, 
java.io.Serializable {
 ...
}
```

I know about the common conversions, but i am stuck on this line of code :

```
getDeserializer().deserialize((TBase <?, ?>) ret, record);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look as

```
getDeserializer().deserialize(ret.asInstanceOf[TBase[_, _]], record)
```

But I suspect the cast may not be necessary (in both Java and Scala), since `ret` already has `TBase[_, _]` as supertype.